# Rails: Unable to save nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: User and WritingSample. A user can have many writing samples. I have a page with a form with extra JS for adding additional writing sample fields -- however, I've disabled this for the time being and I'm trying to get it working with just the one.

What I want to happen: the user types the url of a writing sample into the form and this is stored as a WritingSample row.

The form seems to be working. But I'm clearly not doing something right.

When I submit the form, I can see that `safe_params` contains:

```
"writing_samples_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"url"=>"foo"} permitted: true>}
```

But it looks like User wants an id:

```
> User
User(id: integer, name: string, writing_sample_id: integer)
```

`User.new(safe_params)` returns:

```
<User id: nil, name: "joe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, writing_sample_id: nil>
```

The new user isn't created, and I get the error:

```
user.errors.first
[:"writing_samples.user", "must exist"]
```

What steps do I need to take to store the submitted data in the :url field?

WritingSample:

```
class WritingSample < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :writing_samples
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :writing_samples
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  t.integer  "writing_sample_id"
  t.index ["writing_sample_id"], name: "index_users_on_writing_sample_id"
end

create_table "writing_samples", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "url"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_writing_samples_on_user_id"
end
```

My controller:

```
def create
  user = User.new(safe_params)
  byebug
  if user.save
    redirect_to '/thanks'
  else
    byebug
    redirect_to new_creator_path
  end
end

private

def safe_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :writing_samples_attributes => [:url])
end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: creators_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.label 'Writing samples' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.fields_for :writing_samples do |sample_f| %>
      <%= sample_f.text_field :url %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: At what point do you get an error? With `save`?

Comment: An ID is only needed if you are editing existing records.

Comment: You should also remove the `users.writing_sample_id` column -  the only foreign key needed is `writing_samples.user_id` for a one to many association.